# How to publish build results?

Tags: jenkins

I have a problem with Jenkins. I don`t know how to publish build results.
After build i create zip file with results and i want to show link to this zip file.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

On the configuration page for your build you need to add the post-build option "Archive the artifacts". You enter paths to the files to be archived in the text field.

Comment: Now i have error
<code>ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "myFile". Configuration error?  
ERROR: 'myFile' doesn't match anything: '' exists but not 'myFile'
Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE</code>  
myFile is path to file ex. /home/user/dir/file.zip  
What is wrong?

Comment: The base directory for the path is the Jenkins build workspace so the file to archive must be created within that.

Comment: The "myFile" sounds like strange file name. Shouldn't it be "myFile.zip" or something?

Comment: myFile was only example :).
I create link to my build folder in workspace and now it works.
Thanks for help.

Comment: @user1799537 If you're satisfied with his answer, please accept it so he can get the credit for it. Thanks!